# Positioning the drop down window of a HTML SELECT

Tags: html, css, html-select

I am using an HTML SELECT tag and want to make sure the window that opens when the user hits the arrow to position below the "textbox" part of the control.

The problem is that IE seems to just open the window arbitrarily depending on the selection but I need to ensure consistent positioning as there are other elements on the page that need to remain visible at all times

Here's the current markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 5px">
        <div style="position: relative;">
            <select style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px;">
                <optgroup label="Choice A">
                    <option value="A-A">Sub choice A</option>
                    <option value="A-B">Sub choice B</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="Choice B">
                    <option value="B-A">Sub Choice A</option>
                    <option value="B-B">Sub Choice B</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: This is whats happening]

Comment: That's a very stupid design decision by Microsoft. I see the logic, but normally when I open a dropdown, I want to select something different than what's there already. Furthermore, I want the dropdown to drop **down**.

Comment: Is this an `IE` problem only?

Comment: See here it will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053645/dropdownlist-styling-in-internet-explorer

Comment: @BeatAlex Chrome is fine...

Comment: So it only happens in `IE`?

Comment: @BillK Dang... I was searching so hard to find it... but that's not good news.... damn MS :(

Comment: Only have Chrome and IE so can't tell you about others.

Comment: You may want to use a jQuery plugin like Select2 to make it look and behave the same across all browsers

Comment: Microsoft screwed up a user interface?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry. I'm afraid this is not possible. The problem is `<select>` dropdowns uses browser's native rendering of dropdowns. This means that there is limited styling capability and differ by browsers. I see the behavior you described on my OSX Chrome as well - not opening below the select box.

The only way you can have complete control the styles completely is to use something completely custom - building the `<select>` using DOM and javascript:

Check out this: http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/

When selecting a library, make sure to pick one that transforms the native `<select>` tag into custom - IE the markup shouldn't be custom for your HTML. This is so when browsers don't have JavaScript, your `<select>` dropdown should still work