# How to align this select list of material-ui to bottom line of input block?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a select build by material-ui, all function is fine, but I want to alignt top line of select list to bottom line of input block, how could I do this?

My code :

```
const styles = theme => ({
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit
  }
});

<FormControl className={classes.formControl} fullWidth={true}>
  <InputLabel htmlFor="deviceSource-native-select">Device source</InputLabel>
  <Select
    native={true}
    onChange={this.onDeviceSourceChange}
    inputProps={{
      id: 'deviceSource-native-select',
      name: 'deviceSource'
    }}
  >
    <option value={'Ten'}>Ten</option>
    <option value={'Twenty'}>Twenty</option>
    <option value={'Thirty'}>Thirty</option>
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page?

Comment: Please show your rendered html and css in a [mcve]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have created a CodeSandbox that replicates your issue here: https://codesandbox.io/s/k279v04v3v

Unfortunately, using `native={true}` means that you are at the mercy of specific browser implementations as to how your select dropdown is displayed. [You can't change it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23548412/6702715)

If you are willing to use a non-native select it will be possible by setting the following prop on your Select component:

```
MenuProps={{
  getContentAnchorEl: null,
  anchorOrigin: {
    vertical: "bottom",
    horizontal: "left"
  }
}}
```

Here's a fork of the above CodeSandbox with the select non-native and the above prop set: https://codesandbox.io/s/jpw77oo315