# Align selected item in scrolling html dropdown

Tags: html, css, scroll, alignment

I have a scrolling dropdown, and when someone opens the dropdown, I want the currently selected element to show in the center (if possible, aka it's low/high enough), instead of the browser default - in Firefox, the dropdown view shows the selected element at the end.

[image: undesired]  [image: desired]

Comment: Interesting question, I'm not sure is possible customizing this browser behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do that with your default `select` options.

This question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542687/positioning-the-drop-down-window-of-a-html-select).

Anyway, you could build a custom `select` or could use plugin for custom `select` and then position the dropdown:

https://select2.org/

http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be possible you can center the selected ones but not all the options
so the selected ones you can center it like

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <style>
    select {
      width: 400px;
      text-align-last: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <select name="state" class="ddList">
    <option>Selected</option>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey! I meant that I wanted the currently selected option to show in the middle of the dropdown list when expanded. Sorry if my wording wasn't clear, there are too many things "align" could refer to :(

Answer (score 0):

use some js to re order your options, you could exchange the positions of the selected value with the middle done and you're done

u can get the children of the selecte
put the selected option in a var
get the middle one `let target = option[Math.floor(childrend.length / 2)]`

then a simple exchange of positions
you could set this up as an eventlistener for the **onchange** or something

Comment: Sorry, don't think this is very good UX (can be very confusing); also the reason I want to keep it in the center is to make it easy to select one dropdown option after the other. Currently, you have to scroll a little each time you want to go to the next option. Swapping positions is only a visual thing and doesn't improve this. Interesting answer though!

Comment: Oooooh! ok i got it!! And thanks for the highlight i'm not that good in UX 